# Has anyone managed to connect Motorola HC700 to Windows 7?

Tags: windows-mobile, sync

Has anyone managed to connect Motorola HC700 to Windows 7?

I tried without success.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Motorola MPx220 Driver.
DeviceManager -> HC700 -> Update Driver Software -> Browse my computer ... -> Let me pick from a list ...
manufacturer = Motorola,
model = Motorola MPx220 Smartphone
Normally this driver should be shipped with Win7. Sometimes you have to install it separately. You can find the driver pack on the net.